# Updating Android build gradle version to 3.2.1 is causing error

Tags: android, gradle

Everything worked fine until I updated build gradle to 3.2.1 and now I cannot build my project. I have a task that generates some variant specific code as defined below:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def generateClientIdConfigTask = project.tasks.create(..)
    ....

    variant.variantData.sourceGenTask.dependsOn generateClientIdConfigTask
}
```

This line is causing following error:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
>   sourceGenTask for class:
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData

I already updated distributionUrl in the gradle wrapper as below:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-
>   all.zip

Any help would be appreciated. Is there a different way to write `dependsOn`?

Comment: Did you try compiling a whole new project? Like... the blank activity? If so, create a new project, then copy all the source files and res files to the new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API android plugin was changed. You need to do this (replace `variant.variantData.sourceGenTask` to `variant.variantData.getTaskContainer().sourceGenTask`):

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def generateClientIdConfigTask = project.tasks.create(..)
    ....

    variant.variantData.getTaskContainer().sourceGenTask.dependsOn generateClientIdConfigTask
}
```